# MacOS clicking in unactivated window causes it to move

Tags: macos, storyboard, interface-builder

I have a window in my mac app, and when I click on any control in it, the window moves.  This only happens when the window is not activated (focused?).  If the window is already the main window, it works fine.

What would cause this?  I'm thinking I'm not returning some kind of 'handled' value so that the mouse event is getting passed back to the window's move routine, even though I am not over the move bar.

Thanks for any suggestions!